# Search by text field

Tags: elasticsearch

Here is my index:

```
λ curl -XGET -u elastic:elasticpassword http://192.168.1.71:9200/test/mytype/_search?pretty -d'{"query":{"match_all":{}}}'   
{                                                                                                                            
  "took" : 5,                                                                                                                
  "timed_out" : false,                                                                                                       
  "_shards" : {                                                                                                              
    "total" : 5,                                                                                                             
    "successful" : 5,                                                                                                        
    "failed" : 0                                                                                                             
  },                                                                                                                         
  "hits" : {                                                                                                                 
    "total" : 2,                                                                                                             
    "max_score" : 1.0,                                                                                                       
    "hits" : [                                                                                                               
      {                                                                                                                      
        "_index" : "test",                                                                                                   
        "_type" : "mytype",                                                                                                  
        "_id" : "2",                                                                                                         
        "_score" : 1.0,                                                                                                      
        "_source" : {                                                                                                        
          "name" : "Dio",                                                                                                    
          "age" : 10                                                                                                         
        }                                                                                                                    
      },                                                                                                                     
      {                                                                                                                      
        "_index" : "test",                                                                                                   
        "_type" : "mytype",                                                                                                  
        "_id" : "1",                                                                                                         
        "_score" : 1.0,                                                                                                      
        "_source" : {                                                                                                        
          "name" : "Paul",                                                                                                   
          "pro" : {                                                                                                          
            "f" : "Cris",                                                                                                    
            "t" : "So"                                                                                                       
          }                                                                                                                  
        }                                                                                                                    
      }                                                                                                                      
    ]                                                                                                                        
  }                                                                                                                          
}
```

Here is a default mapping:

```
λ curl -XGET -u elastic:elasticpassword http://192.168.1.71:9200/test/mytype/_mapping?pretty                 
{                                                                                                            
  "test" : {                                                                                                 
    "mappings" : {                                                                                           
      "mytype" : {                                                                                           
        "properties" : {                                                                                     
          "age" : {                                                                                          
            "type" : "long"                                                                                  
          },                                                                                                 
          "name" : {                                                                                         
            "type" : "text",                                                                                 
            "fields" : {                                                                                     
              "keyword" : {                                                                                  
                "type" : "keyword",                                                                          
                "ignore_above" : 256                                                                         
              }                                                                                              
            }                                                                                                
          },
```

I can find by `age` field, but cannot by `name` field. Why ?

```
λ curl -XGET -u elastic:elasticpassword http://192.168.1.71:9200/test/mytype/_search?pretty -d'{"query":{"term":{"age":10}}}'                  
{                                                                                                                                              
  "took" : 6,                                                                                                                                  
  "timed_out" : false,                                                                                                                         
  "_shards" : {                                                                                                                                
    "total" : 5,                                                                                                                               
    "successful" : 5,                                                                                                                          
    "failed" : 0                                                                                                                               
  },                                                                                                                                           
  "hits" : {                                                                                                                                   
    "total" : 1,                                                                                                                               
    "max_score" : 1.0,                                                                                                                         
    "hits" : [                                                                                                                                 
      {                                                                                                                                        
        "_index" : "test",                                                                                                                     
        "_type" : "mytype",                                                                                                                    
        "_id" : "2",                                                                                                                           
        "_score" : 1.0,                                                                                                                        
        "_source" : {                                                                                                                          
          "name" : "Dio",                                                                                                                      
          "age" : 10                                                                                                                           
        }                                                                                                                                      
      }                                                                                                                                        
    ]                                                                                                                                          
  }                                                                                                                                            
}                                                                                                                                              

λ curl -XGET -u elastic:elasticpassword http://192.168.1.71:9200/test/mytype/_search?pretty -d'{"query":{"term":{"name":"Paul"}}}'             
{                                                                                                                                              
  "took" : 5,                                                                                                                                  
  "timed_out" : false,                                                                                                                         
  "_shards" : {                                                                                                                                
    "total" : 5,                                                                                                                               
    "successful" : 5,                                                                                                                          
    "failed" : 0                                                                                                                               
  },                                                                                                                                           
  "hits" : {                                                                                                                                   
    "total" : 0,                                                                                                                               
    "max_score" : null,                                                                                                                        
    "hits" : [ ]                                                                                                                               
  }                                                                                                                                            
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you name field is analyzed by default with the standard analyzer, which lowercases the field. You can either search for `paul` or search in `name.keyword` field with `Paul`.